# Value search for array items got from Dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have list of values here.

```
NSArray *allvalues = [subjectValue allValues]; // subjectValue is Mutable dictionary
```

log printed like below,

```
allvalues: (
        (
        "service3@citicorp.com",
        "IMPORTANT - Documents required"
    ),
        (
        LinkedIn,
        "Do you know Daniel?"
    ),
        (
        “Dave steve”,
        "RE: Development"
    ),
        (
        Angelour TB,
        "Score High on it”
    ),
        (
        MyntraCavin,
        "EORS: Sneak Peek!"
    )
)
```

I want to use Search feature and find the content from this array.
I tried,

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] %@",searchText];
```

and,

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY SELF == %@", searchText];
```

and,

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF == %@", searchText];
```

to get the filtered array values,

```
    NSArray *filteredValues = [allvalues filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    NSSet *keys = [subjectValue keysOfEntriesPassingTest:^BOOL(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
            return [filteredValues containsObject:obj];
        }];
    NSLog(@"subjectValue key desc: %@", keys.description);
    if (keys!=nil)
        filteredUidArray = [keys allObjects];
```

But, filteredValues always returns me nil with the above 3 predicate search. Could someone advise how can I get the values filtered for this kind of array format `allvalues`.

Answer (score 0):

You are over-using the collection classes.  Instead create a custom object for the dictionary values and give this class properties that can be used with predicates:

```
@interface MyValue : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) NSString *someReference;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *someComment;
@end
```